# How can one use a defined channel, in monolog handler from a tagged service?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have the following monolog handler definitions:

```
    # config_prod.yml
    app_generic:
        type: rotating_file
        max_files:      15
        path: "%param.app_logging_config.log_generic_file%"
        level: info
        channels: [app]

    app_api:
         max_files: 15
         path: "%param.app_logging_config.log_api_file%"
         level: info
         channels: [app]
         level: info

    app_response:
        max_files: 15
        path: "%param.app_logging_config.log_response_file%"
        channels: [app]
        level: info
```

And in service.yml, my intention is to inject monolog (`@logger`) with an array of the above defined handlers.

```
#service.yml
app.app_logger:
    class: AppBundle\Classes\AppLogger
    arguments: ['@logger': ['@app_generic', '@app_api', '@app_response']]
    calls:
      - [init, ['%app_logging_config%']
    tags:
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: app }
```

How does one pass arguments to an injected argument?

- Update:

Re-reading the [description](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/logging/channels_handlers.html),  I was going for [this](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/logging/channels_handlers.html#monolog-channels-config) approach, by just tagging on the service definition:

```
app.logger:
    arguments: ['@logger']
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.logger, channel: app }
channels: ['app']
```

Or even ( if I understood correctly), adding a `channels: ['app']` key and just having this in service argument:

```
app.logger:
    arguments: ['@monolog.logger.app']
```

I have not been able to use ( or see via dump ) the handlers defined in config_prod.yml.  I have placed these at top because of other "fingers_crossed" handlers I thought may interfere.

I woud like to know,  why neither of above (documented) approaches seem to work?

Comment: Update - the above works, it just needs to be defined in `config.yml`.  Just in case someone stumbles on this wondering why their custom handlers are not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers in

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        handler1: ...
        handler2: ...
```

are automatically injected in [@logger service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html).

It looks like you need **new** custom logger. Please read about [The DependencyInjection Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)

## Create dependencies

```
services:
    app_generic:
        ....
    app_api:
         ....
    app_response:
        ....
```

## Create custom_logger service

```
custom_logger:
    class: Monolog\Logger
    arguments: ["my logger", ["@app_generic", "@app_api", "@app_response"]
```

## Inject you custom logger in you service

```
app.app_logger:
    class: AppBundle\Classes\AppLogger
    arguments: ['@custom_logger']
    calls:
      - [init, ['%app_logging_config%']
```

Comment: Althoug I "could" ( and may ) use this approach, from reading the docs I assumed I could define the handlers in config_prod.yml, and inject in a service with the following: 

`tags:
            - { name: monolog.logger, channel: ibv }`

Is this possible? I tried as defined in the doc but only default handlers are available when I do `dump($logger->getHandlers());`

Comment: I updated the question if you are curious and have any idea. Thanks friend.

Comment: I did manage to find the solution, I had my handlers defined in config_prod.yml, and when running from cli - config_dev is loaded ! After re-thinking though I agree the approach you suggested is better suited to be configured with distinct logger, seperates cleanly the concerns between framework and application. If the particular bundle is removed, the logging is included in its service defininiition.

Thanks again mate, good-day!